# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've made a constructor (and put it above preload function) like this

```
character = function(CharX,CharY,CharSpeed){
this.x = CharX ;
this.y =  CharY;
this.speed = CharSpeed;
this.AddSpriteSheet = function (SprX,SprY,key) {
this.character = game.add.sprite(SprX,SprY,key);}
};
```

Later in create function I added

```
var Char1 = new character(game.world.width*0.5,game.world.height*0.5,5);
Char1.AddSpriteSheet(game.world.width*0.5,game.world.height*0.5,'character');
Char1.anchor.set(50,50);
```

Console reads

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined"

What have i done wrong?

Edit : Make error more visible

Comment: You never add any property called `anchor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a custom class to represent a character, but it's not a Phaser Sprite, and therefore it doesn't have any of the methods/properties a Sprite does unless you define them yourself. If you want to create your own class to extend Phaser.Sprite, I suggest you look at [this forum post](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/15503-some-oop-technique-in-phaser/#comment-87901) and also [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/extending-sprite-demo-2). Just googling "phaser extend sprite" will help you find some other resources as well.

Essentially, you need to do something like this:

```
function Character(game, x, y) {   
    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y, 'sprite key');   
    // define other properties for your character
}
Character.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
Character.prototype.constructor = Character;
```

And then you would add all of your Character's methods onto the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor `character` does not have a property `anchor`, thus, `Char1.anchor` does not exist, and neither does `Char1.anchor.set`.

Answer (score 0):

'set' of undefined" bca "set" is Pixi's compare to "setTo" Phaser's

Char1.anchor.set(50,50);
replace by 
Char1.anchor.setTo(0.5);// 0.5, 0.5 will point to center of the sprite's square, if that is the intention. 
this is also truth for .scale.setTo();

also if you create new prototype object out of create function i would recommend to follow this example https://phaser.io/examples/v2/games/tanks