# JavaScript/ThreeJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a custom object using ThreeJS called `Model` that is composed of other custom objects I have defined, such as `Part`. This is where I get my error:

```
const Model = function() {
      this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
      this.mesh.name = 'model';

      //creates instance of part
      this.lowerPart = new Part();
      this.lowerPart.position.set(1, 2, 3, -75);  //TypeError here
      this.lowerPart.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
      this.mesh.add(this.lowerPart);
}
```

However, when I run my program, it says that it cannot read the property 'set' in undefined, referencing `this.lowerPart.position.set(1, 2, 3, -75);`.

Here is how I basically defined `Part`:

```
 const Part = function () {
      this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
      this.mesh.name = 'part';

      const partShape = new THREE.Shape();
      partShape.lineTo( 40, 80 );
      partShape.lineTo( 60, 80 );
      partShape.lineTo( 60, 100 );
      partShape.lineTo( 40, 100 );

      //extrude settings defined....

      const partGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(partShape, extrudeSettings);
      const partMesh = new THREE.Mesh(partGeometry, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0x1c4bc9,
        flatShading: true
      }));
      this.mesh.add(partMesh);
    };
    Part.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Object3D.prototype);
    Part.prototype.constructor = Part;
```

Another thing to note in my function `Model` is that when `this.lowerPart` is created, it is labeled as unused. I am unsure of the reason since it is type Object3D which has these properties.

The console also proves that `this.lowerPart` is an instance of `Part`.

I've looked and tried most of the suggested StackOverflow questions related to my problem. Out of all of them, this seems the most relevant: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081177/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-set-of-undefined)
However, it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions to how I can fix my issue is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to derive `Part` from `THREE.Object`, you also have to execute the following line of code in the constructor of `Part` (it should be the first line in the ctor):

```
THREE.Object3D.call( this );
```

Only then it's possible to access properties like `position`, `rotation` or `scale` with an instance of `Part`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, when I added this, it gives me this error: `THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.` I think it may be referring to where I call my `Model` function with `model = new Model();` but it doesn't give me the exact line where the error is occurring.

Comment: I also see that I get another error where I added `THREE.Object3D.call(this);` that says `TypeError: Cannot set property 'uuid' of undefined`

Comment: Any chances to share your code as a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? In such cases, it's much easier to provide help when the community can debug your issue.

Comment: Yes, I just added it in: https://jsfiddle.net/hannahbernal/0bkc8ujw/18/ I'm new to JSFiddle so I wasn't sure how to attach the JS file to the HTML, but what I have now is the basics of my program

Comment: Great! I have cleaned up your fiddle a bit and also fixed the inheritance of your classes. You are now free of runtime errors :) https://jsfiddle.net/0v2ktmfp/

Comment: Thank you for looking it over! However, when I made the changes you made to the entirety of my code, I still come up with the `TypeError: Cannot set property 'uuid' of undefined`, referencing where `THREE.Object3D.call(this)` under my `Model` function.

Comment: Sry, I really don't know why this happens without debugging your code.

Comment: Ok, I think your answer did resolve my issue! I think the problem was that I made an instance of my `Model` and I needed it to be a function, instead of a variable in my case. Thank you for the help!